# Conv2D output shape in CNN too small

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

The input shape in the first Conv2D layer is supposed to be (100, 100, 1) however the output is (None, 98, 98, 200). I understand what 200 and None determine but I'm not sure about 98 as the parameter.
Also, adding to this, I randomly selected 200 as the number of filters in Conv2D for my model. How should I determine a suitable number of filters for my model. Is it based on trial and error? Please help. Thanks!!

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

print(data.shape[1:])
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(200, (3,3), input_shape = data.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(100,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

(100, 100, 1)
Model: "sequential_3"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 98, 98, 200)       2000

---

activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 98, 98, 200)       0

---

max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 49, 49, 200)       0

---

conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 47, 47, 100)       180100

---

activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 47, 47, 100)       0

---

max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2 (None, 23, 23, 100)       0

---

flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 52900)             0

---

dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 52900)             0

---

dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2645050

---

## dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 102

Total params: 2,827,252
Trainable params: 2,827,252
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Answer (score 3):

add `padding="same"` as parameter to `conv2d` and the output dimension will be the same as the input dimension.

The default setting is `padding="valid"` and since you use a 3x3 filter and a step size of 1, you end up with 98x98 dimension because your 3x3 filter fits in 100x100 98 times.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you so much

Comment: If my answer helped you, it would be great if you could 'accept' my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how the dimensions are calculated in the above case

```
img_height = 100
img_width = 100
filter_height = 3
filter_width = 3
img_height-(filter_height-1),img_width-(filter_width-1) #(98,98)
```